# Data Structure for storing several thousand objects with unique index

Tags: java, data-structures

I am reading a huge xml file with Java SAX parser:
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetSchema/v0001/?format=xml
(2.82 MB)

This file contains several thousand 'items', each with properties like 'name', 'level', etc. One of the properties is a unique integer identifier called 'defindex'. I am creating POJOs for each of these items with some of the properties mentioned above as fields (defindex is one of them).

- I will need to read these item objects a lot by searching for the defindex
- I won't change the data fields of objects though

My question is: **How should I store these item objects?**

My first thought was storing them in an array and use the defindex as actual array-index, but the array would be huge and not all defindexes are used, e.g. it jumps from 2k to 30k at one point.

Comment: What's wrong with a map?

Comment: You could use a single user database like [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [hsql](http://hsqldb.org/) to store the data, then you can pull the data out using standard SQL.  These are configurable so that they can run in memory or disk

Comment: @morgano 28000 nulls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/util/Map.html).

`Map` objects store relationships between unique "keys" and values.

Implementations of `Map` are `HashMap` and `TreeMap`, among others. They are generic, with a type parameter for the key and value.

You could use the following. This is DEFINITELY pseudocode; adapt it to however you are going to be manipulating these objects. I did not take the SAX API into account; this just demonstrates how to use a `Map`.

```
Map<Integer, Item> items = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
for (Item itemToRead : file) { // or however you iterate
    items.put(item.getDefindex(), item);
}

// data retrieval
Item itemToRetrieve = items.get(defindexToGet);
```

Comment: You named several implementations of Map like HashMap and TreeMap. Is there a specific implementation of Map that is especially suitable for this kind of problem?

Comment: If your code is not multi-threaded, I would just go with a HashMap. If you need some form of auto-sorting, use TreeMap; that one automagically sorts all keys that you put into it, and you can get the maximum and minimum key. (LinkedHashMap lets you iterate through  your data in the order it was placed in the map.) If your code is multithreaded, you could try the ConcurrentHashMap (package java.util.concurrent), but I'm not well versed in multithreading. In general, pick one whose name ends in `Map`; others tend to be more specialized as far as I know.